# Помогите с API VK!

Tags: php, html, mysql, json, веб-программирование

Всем здравствуйте, подскажите кто работал с API VK, как получить емейл пользователя для авторизации, копался в доках нашел что scope надо подставлять, но не работает. Пример запроса

`$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_id='.$token['user_id'].'&access_token='.$token['access_token'].'&fields=uid,first_name,email,last_name,photo_big&v=5.52'),true);`

Comment: Ну так вы scope при первом запросе отправляли? Плюс пользователь должен согласится с этим запросом. И честно говоря не помню что там в вк, будет если к примеру вы первый раз авторизовывали без мэйла, а потом стали с мэйлом, будет ли он переспрашивать разрешения у пользователя. Как вариант попробуйте у своего пользователя удалить все разрешиния для конкретного приложения. И заново авторизоваться с нормальными скопами.

Comment: Да в первом запросе scope отправлял и потом приложение спрашивает разрешение для доступа к мейлу, разрешаю доступ, но потом всё равно не показывает емейл. Я думаю может это из-за соображений безопасности, хотя как пример такой же авторизации через фейсбук и там всё норм выводит.